# Using google search api to only give results from certain websites

Tags: reactjs, google-search-api

I'm making a react app that uses the google search api allows users to submit websites that they want their search results to come from. I'm having trouble with getting results only from those websites.

I've tried using the sitesearch parameter in my api call which didn't work. The google programmable search engine is able to filter out non-allowed sites however it seems that you have to manually add a list of sites to be searched for it. Any Ideas on what I can do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you could give them a list of popular website and then if there are any other website they want they can just write it and when they write it they will get suggestion form drop down menu?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).